# Calling ssh in a loop is destroying the loop variable context (ksh93 on AIX 7.1)

Tags: ksh, aix

I'm posting this in case anyone else runs into this issue.  I will open a case with IBM, and I'll report back if there's an update from them.

I was having a problem on AIX 7.1 (but not on 6.1) when I'm using a file
to drive a loop (eg:   cat myfile.txt | while read myvar).  Calling ssh
from within the loop causes the loop to exit prematurely on the first iteration.

In my real-life example I wasn't using "ls" to populate the file, but doing so here made it easier to demonstrate.

I've got the following code:

```
#!/usr/bin/ksh93
ssh LESAUN01 -l root "ls -1 c*" > file.list
echo "------------------------------------------"
cat file.list
echo "------------------------------------------"
echo ""
echo "Loop 1"
echo ""
cat file.list | while read file1
do
   echo "    File: $file1"
done
echo ""
echo "Loop 2"
echo ""
cat file.list | while read file2
do
   echo "    File: $file2"
   ssh LESAUN01 -l root "ls -l $file2"
done
echo ""
echo "Done"
exit
```

When I run it from an AIX 6.1 lpar I get these expected results

```
-----------------------------------------
client.txt
customer_handover.log
------------------------------------------

Loop 1

    File: client.txt
    File: customer_handover.log

Loop 2

    File: client.txt
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 91323 Feb 12  2015 client.txt
    File: customer_handover.log
-rw------- 1 root root 27533 Aug 31 18:04 customer_handover.log

Done
```

When run on 7.1 I get this result:

```
------------------------------------------
client.txt
customer_handover.log
------------------------------------------

Loop 1

    File: client.txt
    File: customer_handover.log

Loop 2

    File: client.txt
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 91323 Feb 12  2015 client.txt

Done
```

My solution was to feed the loop from an array instead of a file (after loading the file into the array) which works as expected.

This works on both 6.1 and 7.1

```
#!/usr/bin/ksh93

ssh LESAUN01 -l root "ls -1 c*" > file.list
echo "------------------------------------------"
cat file.list
echo "------------------------------------------"
echo ""
echo "Loop"
echo ""
i=0
set -A file_array
cat file.list | while read line
do
    file_array[ $i ]="$line"
    (( i++ ))
done
for x in "${!file_array[@]}"
do
   echo "    File: ${file_array[$x]}"
   ssh LESAUN01 -l root "ls -l ${file_array[$x]}"
done
echo ""
echo "Done"
exit
```

Which gives this expected result.

```
------------------------------------------
client.txt
customer_handover.log
------------------------------------------

Loop

    File: client.txt
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 91323 Feb 12  2015 client.txt
    File: customer_handover.log
-rw------- 1 root root 27533 Aug 31 18:04 customer_handover.log

Done
```

Comment: As a start, you could move the option before the hostname: ´ssh -l root LEASUN01 ...´ or simply ´ssh root@LEASUN01 ...´

Answer (score 1):

```
cat file.list | while read file2
do
   echo "    File: $file2"
   ssh LESAUN01 -l root "ls -l $file2"
done
```

The output of `cat file.list` is the standard input for every command inside the loop. `ssh` reads from its standard input in order to relay the stream to the remote process, so it's consuming the `cat` output.

A simple fix is to redirect ssh's standard input:

```
cat file.list | while read file2
do
   echo "    File: $file2"
   ssh LESAUN01 -l root "ls -l $file2" < /dev/null
done
```

Comment: "ssh -n" does the redirect if stdin as well, either of which make it act like I expect.   So, the fact that is doesn't consume the input in 6.1, but does in 7.1, mean it was a bug in 6.1 that they  fixed in 7.1? :-)

Comment: I don't think the ssh program's behavior has changed in this regard. My guess is that the older version of ksh may be buffering input to the `read` command. The first call to read might have consumed the full output from `cat` in order to fill the buffer.